# Why CXF / JAXB read whole InputStream into memory before marshalling to SOAP message

Tags: jaxb, cxf, jax-ws, marshalling, jaxb2

**INFO - Sample code**

I've set up sample code (SSCCE) for you to help track the problem:

https://github.com/ljader/test-cxf-base64-marshall

**The problem**

I'm integrating with 3rd party JAX-WS service, so I **cannot change** the WSDL.

The 3rd party webservice expects **Base64** encoded bytes to perform some operation on them - they expect that client sends whole bytes in SOAP message.
They **don't want** to change to MTOM / XOP, so I'm stuck with current requirements.

I decided to use CXF to easily set up sample client, and it worked ok for small files.

But when I try to send BIG data, i.e. 200MB, the CXF/JAXB throws an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.readFrom(ByteArrayOutputStreamEx.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.get(Base64Data.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data.writeTo(Base64Data.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.text(UTF8XmlOutput.java:312)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.leafElement(XMLSerializer.java:356)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$PcdataImpl.writeLeafElement(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MimeTypedTransducer.writeLeafElement(MimeTypedTransducer.java:96)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.writeLeafElement(TransducedAccessor.java:254)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:360)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:696)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:155)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl$1.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:130)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:332)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:339)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:494)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:251)
at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.marshal(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.writeObject(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:617)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.marshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:241)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataWriterImpl.write(DataWriterImpl.java:237)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:117)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
```

**My findings**

I've tracked bug, that based on xsd type "base64Binary", the

> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl

decides, that

> com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Base64Data

should handle marshalling of data from

> javax.activation.DataHandler

During marshalling, the WHOLE data from underlying InputStream is trying to be read http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/Base64Data.java/#311, which causes OOME exception.

**Problem**

CXF uses JAXB during marshalling Java objects into SOAP messages - when marshalling InputStream, the **WHOLE** input stream is read to memory before beeing converted into Base64 binary.

So I want to send ("stream") data from client to server in **chunks** (since the OutputSteam in marshaller is wrapped direct HttpURLConnection), so my client could can handle sending any amount of data.

Especially when many threads would be using my client, the streaming is IMHO very desirable.

I don't have good JAX-WS/CXF/JAXB knowledge, hence the question.

The only materials which I found and may be usefull are:

[Can JAXB parse large XML files in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134189/can-jaxb-parse-large-xml-files-in-chunks)

http://rezarahim.blogspot.com/2010/05/chunking-out-big-xml-with-stax-and-jaxb.html

**The questions**

1. Why CXF/JAXB loads whole InputStream into memory - is not the DataHandler purpouse to prevent such implementation?
2. Do you know any way to change JAXB behaviour to differently marshall InputStream?
3. Do you know different marshallers, which can handle such big data marshalling?
4. As a last resort, maybe you have links to some materials, how to create custom marshaller which would stream the data directly to the server?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any custom marshallers or change JAXB behaviour to achieve what you need - [DataHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html) is your friend here.

Answering your first question: JAXB needs to keep all data in memory because it has to resolve references.

I know you can't change the WSDL references, etc. But still you do have your client's WSDL in your project in order to generate client classes, don't you? So what you can do (I haven't tested this **with third party's WSDL** but might be worth trying) is to add `xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"` into the response XSD element which returns Base64 encoded data. For e.g.:

```
<xsd:element name="generateBigDataResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="result"
                         type="xsd:base64Binary"
                         minOccurs="0"
                         maxOccurs="1"
                         xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Also do not forget to add namespace: `xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"` in the `xsd:schema` element.

What you are doing here - is not changing any WSDL references, just telling JAXB instead of generating `byte[]` to generate `DataHandler`. So what happens when you generate your client classes like that:

```
@Override
public DataHandler generateBigData() {
    try {
        final PipedOutputStream pipedOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
        PipedInputStream pipedInputStream = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream);
        InputStreamDataSource dataSource = new InputStreamDataSource(pipedInputStream, "application/octet-stream");

        executor.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //write your stuff here into pipedOutputStream
            }
        });

        return new DataHandler(dataSource);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //handle exception if any
    }
}
```

You get `DataHandler` as a response type thanks to `xmime`. I suggest you use [PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html), but make sure do the writing in a different thread:

> A piped output stream can be connected to a piped input stream to
>   create a communications pipe. The piped output stream is the sending
>   end of the pipe. Typically, data is written to a PipedOutputStream
>   object by one thread and data is read from the connected
>   PipedInputStream by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects
>   from a single thread is not recommended as it may deadlock the thread.
>   The pipe is said to be broken if a thread that was reading data bytes
>   from the connected piped input stream is no longer alive.

Then you connecting it with the [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) which instance goes into constructor of [InputStreamDataSource](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/multipart/InputStreamDataSource.html) which you then pass into `DataHandler` and return `DataHandler`'s instance. This way your file will be written in chunks and you won't get that exception, more - client will never get the timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **1.** Have you seen my example project (https://github.com/ljader/test-cxf-base64-marshall) to which Im reffering at the begin of my question?
**2.** In that example Im already doing what you are suggesting, yet the OOME still occurs - thats because implementation of JAXB ignores usage of DataHandler and still caches everything into memory (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/runtime/unmarshaller/Base64Data.java/#311)
**3.**Do you have any other ideas how this can be fixed?