# What JAXB uses under the hood?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax, stax

I'm doing a very basic test of performance to unmarshal huge zipped XML file to a basic data structure.

I use the same input stream and same unmarshaller created from JAXB Context.

### 1

Simple approach - default JAXB - takes 18 seconds

```
unmarshaller.unmarshal(createFileInputStream());
```

### 2

Wrap input stream in SAX source to (I think) force using SAX - takes 20 seconds

```
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new InputSource(createFileInputStream());
```

### 3

Trying to force using STAX - takes 40 seconds !

```
XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(createFileInputStream());
unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

To compare simple STAX stream reader loop to extract same data needs only 14 seconds.

I was looking at [Can JAXB parse large XML files in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134189/can-jaxb-parse-large-xml-files-in-chunks)

## Question

Why default approach (passing the input stream) is faster than both SAX and STAX? What is used by default?

Why STAX approach is sooo slooooow while it's a recomended approach in mentioned article?

Comment: What's the runtime classname of the `reader` in your 3rd example?

Comment: I can't check it now. However I use default JDK8 STAX implementation. No Woodstox etc...

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Just debug/look at the source code. You will probably see that `unmarshaller.unmarshal(inputStream)` under the hood does exactly what you do in your 2nd approach: Wrap the input stream in a SAX InputSource. So your approach 1 and 2 should be equally fast.
- Running a single pass for any Java benchmark does often not give useful results, because the JIT has no chance to "warm-up". To estimate your program's runtime behavior, you should add quite a few "dry runs" and then start measuring. Always measure multiple passes and look for max/min/mean/median instead of trusting a single number (there could e.g. be an expensive different background task during one of the runs).
- Your 3rd approach should indeed force using StAX instead of SAX. As @Kayaman says, you should have a look at the canonical classname of `reader` (`.getClass().getName()`) to make sure it is what you expect.

  - StAX readers will not always be faster than SAX readers, it depends on the payload and the implementation you use
  - Woodstox or Aalto will typically significally outperform the JDK's default Xerces parser
  - note that you can (and should) *reuse* the `XMLInputFactory` instead of always creating a new instance
  - note that you should close the `XMLStreamReader` after use (may have performance benefit according to e.g. Woodstox documentation)
- A Java 17 JVM will in many use-cases give a nice additional performance gain  over Java 11 or 8 (expect 5..15%)